# Path of Image in drawable

Tags: android, itextpdf

I am using a library iTextPDF.jar and the following is a line of code from my program

```
Image imageHeader = Image.getInstance(path);
```

How to specify the path of an Image that I have stored in drawable?

Thanking you in  advance,
Sreekanth

Answer (score 0):

you can get the image id via runtime but i didnt find any solution to get the path 
you can use this

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_resource", "id", getPackageName());
```

This gives the id of the image which can be used at any place
check this for example http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=17846

Answer (score 0):

First you can convert the image into a byte array

```
Drawable d;
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
```

Then you can pass this byte[] to the get

```
Image imageHeader = Image.getInstance(bitmapdata);
```

getInstance method also accepts byte []  instead of Path of Image in drawable.

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score -1):

If you are having an image in drawable folder we use

```
R.drawable.imagefile
```

to  refer it

Comment: Nope that is not the case,I must get the path of the Image in the drawable folder.Like we refer to the files in SD Card.